# How do you hide specific items in recyclerview and remove its divideritemdecoration?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Hey guys i'm currently trying to hide some of the items in my recyclerview based on a unique userID from Firebase database. Since my recyclerview displays a reference in Firebase, i want to show only the items that were added by other users. Every single item has a reference to who added the item so i was thinking of using this to filter the list. I am using FirebaseAdapter and so i have incorporated the following in OnBindViewHolder to hide the item:

```
if (!item.getID.equals(user.getUid())) {
                    //Set displayName and amount
                    holder.displayName.setText(bet.getDisplayName());
                    holder.amount.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", bet.getAmount()));
else{
                    holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                }
```

But now the item decorator will still draw the borders so i've tried to override getitemoffsets as suggested from other similar questions:

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration =
                new DividerItemDecoration(betRecyclerView.getContext(),
                        recyclerLayoutManager.getOrientation()){
                    @Override
                    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                        if(view.getVisibility() != View.GONE){
                            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
                        } else{
                            outRect.set(0,0,0,0);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                        super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
                    }
                };
```

This leaves me with the following result, the lines are less pronounced than before overriding the getitemoffset method but you can still see which sections have the hidden items. So how do i completely get rid of the thicker lines so the hidden items are completely gone? I am also open to other suggestions such as querying my database, but from my research it seems that you cannot query firebase to exclude a certain value.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igox4.jpg)